# How to get custom fields from get_post using single page?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a news page where it display all the news and there is a read more button with a permalink function. When it is clicked it will redirect the user into single page news for more information although I can't query the custom fields.

post type: news
meta: news

Thank you in advance!

anyway here is my code

```
$post_id = get_the_ID();
$queried_post = get_post($post_id);
$test = get_custom_field('picture-description', TRUE);
$title = $queried_post->post_title;
echo $title;
echo '<br/>';
echo $test;
echo $queried_post->post_content;
```

Comment: I think this has to be done in the post loop...  have you tried this instead: get_post_meta($post_id, 'picture-description', TRUE);

Comment: Are you in a post loop?

Comment: I have tried it sir but error. I'm new into wordpress can you guide me please?

Comment: can you do a var_dump($post_id); and see if it returns anything

Comment: You might need to use: `get_post_meta($post_id, '_picture-description', TRUE);`

Answer (score 2):

Here are some things you can try:

**Make sure your stuff is in a post loop**

*http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop*

```
<?php 
if ( have_posts() ) {
    while ( have_posts() ) {           
       $test = get_custom_field('picture-description', TRUE);
       the_title();
       echo '<br/>';
       the_content();
    } // end while
} // end if
?>
```

**Try an alternative function**

*http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta*

```
get_post_meta($post_id, 'picture-description', TRUE);
```

**Ensure you are in the right file.**

> For a post single the naming convention of the file should be
>   something like single.php or single-posttype.php

[image]

Let me know if any of these things work.

Comment: you `get_post` on `while ( have_posts() )` with the id you got from current query ?? this `$queried_post->post_title;` is just the same with `get_the_title()` in this scenario... the best suggestion would be just to forget about `get_post($post_id);` and just use the current query... well, my point is basing the fact that the OP is using `get_the_ID();`

Comment: Yeah I just pasted his code into the middle of the loop to illustrate I think he needed to be in a post loop.  But I will edit the question to make it a little bit better.

Comment: @Reigel feel free to make more modifications to the answer to make it better :)

Comment: you got it covered ;)

Comment: Sorry for the late reply sir gonna try it now. Thank you!

Comment: Hello sir I don't get it kindly check this.


<code>
    $post_id = get_the_ID();


$args = array(
        'post_type' => 'news',
        'p' => $post_id
    );

$post_query = new WP_Query($args);

     if ($post_query -> have_posts() ) {
       while ( $post_query -> have_posts() ) {           
          $test = get_custom_field('picture- description', TRUE);
            the_title();
           echo '<br/>';
           the_content();
         } // end while
      } // end if

</code>

Comment: What is the error you are getting.  Can you turn wp_debug to true in your wp-config.php and then take a screen shot and post it above.